# Angular: Setting timeout in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm running Unit Tests using jasmine 2.5 and karma 1.4.
For a few of them I receive timeout errors:

```
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 7 0.0.0) BeratungdetailsComponent should be in Testfall 2 Soring 29 FAILED
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:3072:31)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:2839:47)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:3134:38)
    at timer (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1512:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:4160:29)
```

So I tried the overloade it-method from jasmin, specifing the timeout for this test:

```
it('should be checkGespraechspartner is true when Name and Vorname is not set', () => {
  const formPerson = component.personComponent.personForm;
  const personVornameControl = formPerson.get('personVorname');
  const personNameControl = formPerson.get('personName');

  personVornameControl.setValue('');
  personNameControl.setValue('');
  expect(component.personComponent.checkGespraechspartner()).toEqual(true);   
}, 25000);
```

I still got an timeout.

So I tried setting the timeout direktly within the beforeEach-method:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 25000;
```

This works just fine.

I thought by using the overloaded it-method (specifing the timeout as a third parameter) jasmin would use this value instead of the default-timeout.

So I'm a bit confused when to use the overloaded it method.

Comment: what is your expectation? revise your post as it confuses.